# How should I upload a large amount of data from iOS app to Rails server?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, bigdata

I want to upload from iOS app a large amount a data (it can be a files) to Rails server. I want to be able to handle the Internet connection lost and resume a transfer after Internet connection restored.

1. What I should to use: web sockets, HTTP or something other?
2. What are the useful tools/gems/libraries for iOS and Rails?

Comment: You should add more tags to your question to consult your target audience. Like "iOS" or "rails" or programming language tags. Also, this question is broad, it may is voted for close. What did you try so far? What is your research effort?

Comment: Oh... I forgot about tags, thanks. I'm looking for a general approach and tips. I haven't try anything yet, because I would like to get some tips first. Moreover, I'm just newbie in iOS and especially looking for a convenient solutions for this platform it's quite difficult for me. I've researched a something about sockets, streaming, HTTP, etc.
So... I'm not expecting a ready-to-use or copy-paste soultion, but some hint what directions should I use to do that quite easy, fast and efficiently.